# Manipulate array by jQuery from a cookie

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, cookies

I'm trying to read an array from a cookie. The array code below is stored in a cookie. What is the best way of getting the value back from the cookie. I need to use the value in the array and thinking for each loop should do the trick but I don't know how to go about it.

```
 "Nissan": [{
         "model": "Sentra",
         "doors": 4
     },
     {
         "model": "Maxima",
         "doors": 4
     }
 ],
 "Ford": [{
         "model": "Taurus",
         "doors": 4
     },
     {
         "model": "Escort",
         "doors": 4
     }
 ]
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: JSON.parse?....

Comment: Please provide more info about the current information structure and the desired structure.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest AND after fixing your JSON string:

```
var arr = JSON.Parse( jsonString ); //jsonString = Your JSON string in your cookie.

// Loop
for ( var i in arr )
{
    // Access the propertis
    alert( arr[i] );
}
```

Please note, `JSON.stringify()` is used to convert a JSON `object` to a `string` and `JSON.parse()` is used to convert a `string` to a JSON `object`

Comment: What will be the full code. And would i need to use a for each loop?